# get element from json array in laravel 4

Tags: mysql, json, laravel

hi guys i'm making an api in laravel 4 !! so im getting data that i store and return a json response  everyting is good but just one thing :)

this is part of th code that return a response

```
if( $user->save() )
        {
            $id = DB::table('users')
            ->where('pseudo','LIKE',$pseudo)
            ->select('id')
            ->get();

            return Response::json(array(
                'status'  => 'ok',
                'message'  => 'success',
                'userId' => $id 

            ));
        }
```

the reponse is

```
{"status":"ok","message":"success","userId":[{"id":11}]}
```

but i whant to get this response

```
{"status":"ok","message":"success","userId":11}
```

how can i do it im trying but nothing chaged ! thx

Answer (score 0):

You are setting 'userId' equal to the entire $id object returned from the query. You really just want

```
return Response::json(array(
                'status'  => 'ok',
                'message'  => 'success',
                'userId' => $id['id'] 

            ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just something a little bit neater:

```
$id = DB::table('users')
            ->where('pseudo','LIKE',$pseudo)
            ->pluck('id'); // Retrieve first result, column 'id'
```